# OkHttp3 newCall.execute() causes hang. HttpUrlConnection code works fine

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, okhttp

My issue is the following statement causes the exiting program to hang for at least 30 seconds.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
...
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .method("POST", RequestBody.create(mediaType, ""))
                .url(myURL)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").build();
...
try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) //! Causes hang for some reason
        {
            resBody = response.body().string();
        }
```

This method is passed and I get a successful response. But when the program gets to the last statement, it hangs for around 30 more seconds.

If I switch up to using HttpUrlConnection code, no issues are seen.

I tried using jstack  but not sure what I am looking at. Also you cannot "tail" with jstack.
Something with the OkHttp3 lib is causing this.

I *am* hitting an **https** mulesoft API in case you need some details. But the Mulesoft application logs show a clean request and response, no errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with resources can call Closeable interface's method.

Closeable is a source or destination of data that can be closed.
 * The close method is invoked to release resources that the object is
 * holding (such as open files)

Comment: Funny I always seem to find the answer after I post to SO. https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5832 Basically this "daemon" thread was fixed in a later version. I just updated my maven stanza and we're off to the races. But thanks for the suggestiion.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5832 - says to simply get the latest libraries for OkHttp3.